# Scheduled Notifications with Firebase and background running

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want my Firebase to send scheduled push notifications to all the users of my application and if the app is in the background; run some code and send some stuff to the server.

I'm a bit lost because it's impossible to do so with the notification console from Firebase.

Then, I was interested in Firebase Cloud Messaging, but in the documentation, it says that the connection to FCM should be ended :

> When your app goes into the background, disconnect from FCM

-[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#receive_messages_through_messaging)

What can I do? Should I take a look at services like Parse? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem building a server where the user register his token (unique identifier) to a database. There is also a PHP script for sending push notifications. You can find all of this [here](http://www.easyapns.com/).

I edited the PHP script to send a payload which contains :

```
["content-available"] = "1"
```

This payload will trigger what you want to do when your app is in the background.

I used a crontab on my server to regularly send push notifications.

The notification console from Firebase can send push notification but not silent push notification that we want in my case.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Notification messages don't execute your application code when your app is in the background. All messages sent from the Firebase console are Notification messages. So you can't currently use the Firebase console for what you are describing.

However you can send Data messages from your app server which can trigger background execution of code. You will have to manage the scheduling yourself on your app server.

Comment: How can I setup an app server ? (I can't find any good tutorial on it). Is Parse a good way to do so ?

Comment: Parse is shutting down soon so I would not advise using that. Check this link to get started with an app server https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: I already checked this documentation, I don't understand anything on how to implement my app-server. That's why I was looking for another service like Parse... So if you have a great tutorial on how to make an app server with FCM or a good alternative to Parse... Thanks.