# How can we schedule push notification from Firebase in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to develop an iOS app. I want to send notification to user one day(one day or 2 days or 3 days this has to be selected by user in settings) prior to his offer expired. How can I do it in Firebase. Can we need to run some code in Firebase? Please help me out.

Comment: I think Firebase doesn't support device to device notification

Comment: this is nothing but push notification right ...?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059360/scheduled-notifications-with-firebase-and-background-running

Answer (score 0):

You have to Create First audiences related to Notification Day.

> https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#create-an-audience

And after generate Notification from Firebase console to specific audience.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/